# How does an asker know whether his question was migrated?

Tags: support, migrated-questions

Yesterday, I tried answering a question, and it was migrated from Stack Overflow [to Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/133524/what-things-do-i-need-to-become-expert-asp-net-mvc/133526). Later, it was closed as not a real question.

However, I am not concerned much about this question but rather would like to know if a question is migrated from one SE site to other, how the does the user, who asked the question, know that it is migrated?

Comment: @gnat thanks for the tag addition to the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The next time they visit the site where they originally asked their question, they'll get a giant notification banner that tells them the migration happened. This notification also applies to anyone who answered the question, as well.

Comment: Thanks @mark trepp. i have not answered the question on stackoverflow but on programmers forum and moreover the user don't have account on programmers forum then how will he be able to comment/query etc

Comment: @Devjosh The first time they visit Programmers after the migration, an account will be created for them (same goes with any answerers) and their post linked to that account. Sometimes this doesn't happen smoothly: in this case, flagging the post after migration alerts the moderators to do it manually.

Comment: ok so this all happens when a question is migrated! thanks @mark for making my question proper and satisfying my additional queries